# Strict aliasing seems inconsistant

Tags: c++, gcc, strict-aliasing

Had a couple of bugs from strict aliasing and so thought I would try to fix all of them. Having looked in some detail at what it is it seems sometimes GCC doesn't issue a warning, and also that some things are impossible to implement. At least by my understanding every below is broken. So is my understanding wrong, is there a correct way to do all these things, or does some code just have to technically break the rule and be well covered by system tests?

The bugs were from some code where char and unsigned char buffers were mixed, e.g. like below:

```
size_t Process(char *buf, char *end)
{
    char *p = buf;
    ProcessSome((unsigned char**)&p, (unsigned char*)end);
    //GCC decided p could not be changed by ProcessSome and so always returned 0
    return (size_t)(p - buf);
}
```

Changing this to the below seemed to fix the problem, although it still involves a cast so I am not sure why this now works and is warning free:

```
size_t Process(char *buf, char *end)
{
    unsigned char *buf2 = (unsigned char *)buf;
    unsigned char *p = buf2;
    unsigned char *end2 = (unsigned char*)end;
    ProcessSome(&p, end2);
    return (size_t)(p - buf2);
}
```

Also there is a bunch of other places that seem to work without warnings

```
//contains a unsigned char* of data. Possibly from the network, disk, etc.
//the buffer contents itself is 8 byte aligned.
const Buffer *buffer = foo();
const uint16_t *utf16Text = (const uint16_t*)buffer->GetData();//const unsigned char*
//... read utf16Text. Does not even seem to ever be a warning


//also seems to work fine
size_t len = CalculateWorstCaseLength(...);
Buffer *buffer = new Buffer(len * 2);
uint16_t *utf16 = (uint16_t*)buffer->GetData();//unsigned char*
len = DoSomeProcessing(utf16, len, ...);
buffer->Truncate(len * 2);
send(buffer);
```

And some with...

```
struct Hash128
{
    unsigned char data[16];
};
...
size_t operator ()(const Hash128 &hash)
{
    return *(size_t*)hash.data;//warning
}
```

A non char case. This doesn't have a warning, and even if it is bad, how do I avoid it (Both ways seem to work)?

```
int *x = fromsomewhere();//aligned to 16 bytes, array of 4
__m128i xmm = _mm_load_si128((__m128*i)x);
__m128i xmm2 = *(__m128i*)x;
```

Looking at other API's there seems to be various cases as well that by my understanding violate the rule (have not come across a Linux/GCC specfic one, but sure there would be one somewhere).

1. CoCreateInstance Has a void** output param requiring an explicit pointer cast. Direct3D has some like this as well.
2. LARGE_INTEGER is a union that will likely have read/writes to different members (e.g. some code might use high/low, then some other might read the int64).
3. I recall the CPython implementation quite happily casts a PyObject* to a bunch of other stuff that happens to have the same memory layout at the start.
4. A lot of hash implementations I have seen will cast the input buffer to a uint32_t*, then perhaps use uint8_t to handle the 1-3 bytes at the end.
5. Pretty much every memory allocator implementation I have seen uses char* or unsigned char*, which must then be cast to the desired type (possibly via a returned void*, but internally to the allocate at least it was a char)

Comment: Does your first example actually exhibit the behavior of always returning zero, or is it just similar to code that does?  I haven't been able to reproduce that behavior.

Comment: Pretty much exactly that, just different function names. This was with gcc 4.4.5 on a modified corporate red hat targeting x64. The whole lot got inlined however so it may be very specific to how GCC decided to optimise the overall thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, pointers to `char` and to `unsigned char` are pretty much
exempted from rules regarding string aliasing; you are allowed
to convert any type of pointer to a `char*` or an `unsigned 
char*`, and look at the pointed to object as an array of `char`
or `unsigned char`.  Now, with regards to your code:

```
size_t Process(char *buf, char *end)
{
    char *p = buf;
    ProcessSome((unsigned char**)&p, (unsigned char*)end);
    //GCC decided p could not be changed by ProcessSome and so always returned 0
    return (size_t)(p - buf);
}
```

The issue here is that you're trying to look at a `char*` as if
it were an `unsigned char*`.  That's *not* guaranteed.  Given
that the cast is clearly visible, g++ is being a bit obtuse
about not turning the strict aliasing analysis off
automatically, but technically, it is covered by the standard.

In

```
size_t Process(char *buf, char *end)
{
    unsigned char *buf2 = (unsigned char *)buf;
    unsigned char *p = buf2;
    unsigned char *end2 = (unsigned char*)end;
    ProcessSome(&p, end2);
    return (size_t)(p - buf2);
}
```

on the other hand, all of the conversions involve `char*` and
`unsigned char*`, both of which may alias anything, so the
compiler is required to make this work.

With regards to the rest, you don't say what the return type of
`buffer->GetData()` is, so it's hard to say.  But if it is
`char*`, `unsigned char*` or `void*`, the code is fully legal
(except for a missing cast in the second use of
`buffer->GetData()`).  As long as all of the casts involve
a `char*`, an `unsigned char*` or a `void*` (ignoring `const`
qualifiers), then the compiler is required to assume that there
is a possible aliasing: when the original pointer has one of
these types, it could have been created by means of a cast from
a pointer to the target type, and the language guarantees that
you can convert any pointer into one of these types, and back to
the original type, and recover the same value.  (Of course, if
the `char*` wasn't originally a `uint16_t`, you may end up with
alignment problems, but the compiler generally can't know this.)

With regards to the last example, you don't indicate the type of
`hash.data`, so it's hard to say; if it is `char*`, `void*` or
`unsigned char*`, the language guarantees your code
(technically, provided that the char pointer was created by
converting a `size_t*`; in practice, provided that the
pointer is sufficiently aligned and the pointed to bytes do not
form a trapping value for a `size_t`).

In general: the only really guaranteed way of "type punning" is
by `memcpy`.  Otherwise, the pointer casts, such as you are
doing, are guaranteed as long as it is to or from a `void*`,
`char*` or `unsigned char*`, at least as far as aliasing is
concerned.  (From one of these could result in alignment
problems, or accessing a trapping value if you dereference it.)

Note that you may get additional guarantees from other
standards.  Posix requires something like:

```
void (*pf)();
*((void**)&pf) = ...
```

to work, for example.  (Generally, casting and dereferencing
immediately will work, even with g++, *if* you don't do anything
else in the function where aliasing might be relevant.)

And all of the compilers I know will allow using a `union` for
type punning, some of the time.  (And at least some, including
g++, will fail with legal uses of `union` in other cases.
Correctly handling a `union` is tricky for the compiler writer
if the `union` isn't visible.)

Comment: I'm always in awe of people who can keep track of the aliasing rules. +1 :)

Comment: buffer always contains a unsigned char array. GetData just returns the (const) unsigned char*. The hash is just a struct with a unsigned char data[16]. Updated the code samples. What about the CPython thing, I recall socket addresses do something similar with sockaddr as well.

Comment: What allows the compiler to assume that `p` can't be changed in the first example?  Even though `&p` is cast to an `unsigned char **`, can the compiler assume that that pointer will never be cast back to a `char **` during the call to `ProcessSome`?

Comment: @VaughnCato The types `unsigned char**` and `char**` are unrelated types.  The rules are more or less the same as those for `int*` and `double*`.

Comment: @WillNewbery Re the CPython casting, there are special rules which apply when the initial sequences of several different POD-structs are identical.  This is for reasons of C compatibility; this is the classical way of implementing the equivalent of inheritance in C (which is exactly what CPython is doing).  Presumably, g++ will also handle this correctly.  Note that it only applies in cases where the types in question are complete, and in C++, for POD types.  And I could only find a reference to it for union members in the standard, even though I've only seen it used with pointers.

Comment: Does that mean that `unsigned char **p2 = (unsigned char **)&p; char **p3 = (char **)p2; ++*p3;` is UB? (where `p` is a `char *` as in the first example)

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes.  The only exceptions involve pointers to `void` and to character types.  Neither `unsigned char*` nor `char*` are `void` or a character type, so there are no special exceptions involving pointers to them.

Comment: I thought this had to do with alignment requirements.  For example, as covered in N3242, 5.2.10p7.  Surely a `char *` and an `unsigned char *` (as objects) have the same alignment requirements.

Comment: "_being a bit obtuse_" That's the exact same point Linus was making, and I think it's a terrible proposition: what if the compiler allows something in a few cases because the optimizer let him "see" what you are doing, but then, for a trivial change in the code (possibly elsewhere), it doesn't allow it anymore?

Comment: "the only really guaranteed way of "type punning" is by `memcpy`". Many people don't realise that this is an incredibly useful fact. Anything `memcpy` can do, `memmove` can do better. For example, you can `memmove` from a block of memory *to itself* to get a *zero-cost* reliable solution to the strict aliasing issue.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The Common Initial Sequence guarantees rule significantly predate the notion that compilers might impose type-based aliasing restrictions.  There was no need to explicitly specify that those guarantees applied to pointer-based accesses since it would have been impractical for compilers to uphold such guarantees with pointers to things that might be union members without also upholding them for structures that weren't.

Answer (score 0):

`char`/`unsigned char` pointers are exempt from the strict aliasing rules.

The union trick is technically an aliasing error, but mainstream compilers explicitly allow it anyway.

So some of your examples are valid (and some are UB according to the language, but well-defined by the compiler).

But yes, there's plenty of code which violates the aliasing rules. Note also that MSVC doesn't do optimizations based on strict aliasing, and so especially code which is written for Windows may be prone to violating strict aliasing rules.

Comment: So if char/unsigned char are always exempt (I thought it was just the T* to char* cast, not the other way), what is wrong with my 128->size_t hash conversion and with the original Process (which GCC actually broke on release builds)? Also which are really UB?

Comment: Oof, all good questions. I can't recite the aliasing rules by heart. They're awfully complicated, as it seems you know. :) Sorry. If I remember, I'll try to look it up later

Comment: It's worth pointing out though, that GCC's strict aliasing warnings *are* inconsistent. Correctly detecting all aliasing violations is computationally infeasible to do. So GCC warns you about the cases it's able to detect, but not getting any aliasing warnings doesn't mean that no aliasing violations exist in your code.

Comment: @WillNewbery To/from `char*`, `unsigned char*` and `void*` are guaranteed to be value preserving: you can convert a pointer to a `char*`, and then convert it back to the original type, and you're guaranteed to get the same value.  And if the compiler cannot see the original conversion, but only the `char*`, it has to assume that the `char*` might have come from such a conversion.

Comment: @WillNewbery In your first example, you're _not_ converting to/from a `char*`, but from a `char**` to an `unsigned char**`.  No guarantees there.

Comment: @jalf With g++, you can turn the aliasing analysis off, using `-fno-strict-aliasing` (which I would recommend in any code where you're type punning).  The documentation for this option also specifies the limits of what the compiler supports with regards to unions.